# How do I create a page that displays the homepage?

Tags: pages, homepage

sorry for the somewhat odd question.

I need to create a wordpress page that basically just displays the / page.

How would i go about doing such a thing?

The homepage itself isn't either a post or a page.

I need it to be a page to run a script on it (can't be done through the editor either)

This is a tad hard to explain....

any help would be appreciated...

Comment: "This is a tad hard to explain..." --> Try harder, please - your issue is a tad hard to understand as well. ;)

Comment: Ha, yes i'm aware.

Comment: I'm looking to create a page that's a direct copy of the homepage.

Comment: Try even harder. That last comment confused me even more.

Comment: Ok, Ok.....try this

Comment: I need to be able to create a page, in wordpress, that displays index.php as it would when you'd first land on the webpage....

Answer (score 1):

Download the `index.php` theme file to your local hard drive. Create a copy of the `index.php` and name it `home.php`. Upload the `home.php` theme file to your theme directory.

Go to Reading Settings (Settings > Reading) page in the WordPress dashboard. Select the *Your latest posts* option and click on the Save Changes button.

Any change you make to the `home.php` theme file should now only change the home page of your web site.